# Error: "jQuery is not defined", but jquery is loaded

Tags: jquery

but trying to operate jquery validate plugin 1.6 but im getting this error in Chrome inspector:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not
>   defined. ------  jquery.validate.min.js:15

I'm loading jquery 1.4.4 in my page.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Are you including `jquery.validate` before `jquery`?

Comment: could you provide a code example?

Comment: Specifically, can you quote your `script` tags (in the order in which they appear in your document)?

Comment: @pekka, im including jquery before jquery.validate, I think is the correct order.

Comment: do you use html5 caching (in mainifest)? If yes then make all js files cached or none

Comment: Can you show the code of your head section?

Comment: Ok, it's true, the problem is the order, im writing them in the html file in an order, but then are loaded in the order inverse.

Comment: Seeing as this doesn't seem to have a direct answer yet (at least not when searching), I'm adding this as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure `jquery` is loaded first, before the validation plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you're not importing jQuery more than once!  In my case, I began my `.cshtml` view in asp.net with

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

and then at the end of my code, I forgot that I left this behind:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Importing jQuery more than once on a page can cause no end of issues.  See [this bug report from the jQuery project](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10066) for more information, but this quote stood out to me:

> [If you have jQuery referenced more than once on a page]...As jQuery
>   script executes it re-initializes $ and $.prototype, which removes all
>   existing plug-ins. The host page stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that having all the various .js files included ONLY ONCE EACH, and in the right order (jquery before validate, before unobtrusive) is critical to the application running right.  I spent 2 days debugging before I seriously looked at this.  Bundles can add .js files in unpredictable order if they have an * to catch all files.  Break the bundles into smaller bundles so you can control the order they are loaded.  If the .js file is loaded in _layout, don't add it again in the individual view.  I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could not control the sequence of scripts loading, because basic `jquery` script is a part of functionality I extend and I additionally include `jquery.validate`. So what helped me was `defer` attribute which puts off the given script loading until the page is fully parsed:

```
<script defer src="../js/jquery.validate"></script>
```